# Need JavaScript example for fetch() etc

Tags: javascript

I want to learn such new JavaScript features as fetch() and arrow functions. To this end, I selected a function from a recent app, and attempted to replace older features with new. Very little success. Here's my original function:

```
function popNames(arNumbers,ctrlName) {
  var arSortedList = [];
  var strNameList = "";
  $.getJSON("NAME.json").done(function(zdata) {
$.each(arNumbers, function(i, ydata) {
  $.each(zdata.NAME, function(k,v) {
    if(v.idName == ydata) {// important: === did NOT work
          if(ctrlName) arSortedList.push(v.last + ", " + v.first + ";" + v.idName);
      else arSortedList.push(v.last + ", " + v.first);
    }
  });   // each element of NAME.json
}); // each idName value in the array passed
if(ctrlName) {
  setOptions(arSortedList, ctrlName);
} else {
  strNameList = arSortedList.join();
}
  });   // getJSON NAME
}
```

I was successful using this line:

```
fetch("NAME.json").then(zdata => zdata.json())
```

but nothing I did after that worked. I'd appreciate seeing an example from which I can learn.

Comment: Add another `.then(zdata => { ... })` to that and use it the same as your callback in your `.done()`

Comment: What exactly did you try that didn't work? Did you try: `fetch("NAME.json").then(zdata => zdata.json()).then(zdata => $.each(arNumbers,....` ?

Comment: Better to name the first `then` argument `response` to minimize confusion .. `fetch("NAME.json").then(response => response.json()).then(zdata=> $.each....`

Comment: You have a comment that says "important: === did NOT work". I would suggest first fixing your code before asking us to help you with this conversion. How can we know what that failing code is supposed to do?

Comment: `(zdata => zdata.json())` is short hand for `(zdata=>{ return zdata.json() })`. Are you sure you want to be returning there?

Comment: @AndrewMacNaughton yes because `response.json()` returns a promise

Comment: What is the purpose of `strNameList`? You never read its value, and the variable is lost when the function completes...

Comment: What is `zdata.NAME`? An array? Or a plain object? Given your rate of participation in this thread, I think I will move on now... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I realize that I tried to change too much at once, and need to work through one change at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function popNames(arNumbers,ctrlName) {
    let arSortedList = [];
    let strNameList = "";
    fetch("NAME.json").then(zdata => zdata.json())
    .then(zdata => {
        for(const ydata of arNumbers)   {
            for(const v of zdata.NAME) {
                if(v.idName == ydata) {     // important: === did NOT work
                    if(ctrlName) arSortedList.push(v.last + ", " + v.first + ";" + v.idName);
                    else arSortedList.push(v.last + ", " + v.first);
                }
            }
        }
        if(ctrlName) {
            setOptions(arSortedList, ctrlName);
        } else {
            strNameList = arSortedList.join();
        }
    }); // getJSON NAME
}
```

I was researching why I couldn't next two Array.forEach statements, and discovered a new iterable construction (for...of).